# Transform a binary table from a basket format table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table called userItems that has the following format:

```
    user_id    tag_id
1   27938 wordpress
2   27938      CSS3
3   27938     HTML5
4   27938     MySQL
5   27934    drupal
6   27934    joomla
```

This is just the head of the table, but it is a representation of the rest of the data. It just consists of users and their belonging tags. Now I want to transform this into a binary format (do not know if that is the correct name), just as the example below:

```
   user tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
2   33    0    0    1    0    0    0
3   42    0    0    0    0    0    0
4   51    0    0    0    0    0    0
5   62    0    0    0    0    0    0
6   75    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

The 1 indicates that the user has that tag. In my case for example wordpress. And a 0 that he does not have that tag. So user 27934 would have a 1 at drupal and joomla.

How would I go about changing my first table to the second? Some hints or best practices could really help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always nicer if you provide a reproducible example.

However,

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2), tag_id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))

print(df)

second_table <- table(df)
print(second_table)
```

The function `table()` does the trick creating the `contingency table` starting from your `data.frame`.

Finally, if you want the resulting table as `data.frame` class instead of `table` class:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(second_table)
```